# Debugging an Invoke() call causes debugger to stop working

Tags: c++, multithreading, winforms, visual-studio-2017, invoke

I have a method for a WinForm which is called by a thread other than the one the WinForm was created on. When debugging, I get to a line which calls `this->Invoke();` and the debugger seems to skip the line and continue normal execution. But normal execution would have the program loop and continually reach the `Invoke` call, but never does return to it.

I've been experiencing this in Visual Studio 2013 and 2017.

```
//GUI.h
delegate void Whatever(System::String ^ text);

void SetConsoleTextBoxText(System::String^ input)
{
    if (this->consoleTextBox->InvokeRequired)
    {
        Whatever^ we = gcnew Whatever(this, &GUI::SetConsoleTextBoxText);
        this->Invoke(we, gcnew array<Object^> { input }); //debugger hits this and breaks
    }
    else
    {
        this->consoleTextBox->Text = input;
        this->consoleTextBox->Refresh();
    }
}

ref struct Globals {
    static GUI ^ gui; //this is my "Global WinForm"
};
```

---

```
//Different .cpp file
//Running on a different thread than the WinForm "GUI" was made on

MethodThatIsCalledALotInALoop()
{
    System::String^ sysStr = "some string";

    GUI_Example_Receive::Globals::gui->SetConsoleTextBoxText(sysStr);
}
```

---

I've been trying to work out issues with updating that `ConsoleTextBox` for a while and have been having difficulties debugging this issue.

Is my syntax wrong?

Are my debugging set to ignore a first error?

Why would the debugger execute/skip a line and then continue to run the program without ever hitting the error again?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible that the control's (or form's) window handle has not been created yet? Check IsHandleCreated because if it is not then you should not try to set the text, as this may cause the handle to be created on the wrong thread.

Comment: Hey @Ben, the textbox it is definitely created already, but just to check, I included the statement `if(this->consoleTextBox->IsHandleCreated)` and it does indeed return `true`.

Comment: Can I suggest you move the work to a separate function `SetConsoleTextBoxTextImpl` i.e. `Whatever^ we = gcnew Whatever(this, &GUI::SetConsoleTextBoxTextImpl);` so that you don't perform the check twice

Comment: That's kind of the point though. I can call `SetConsoleTextBoxText` from any thread and it will check if it needs to `Invoke` via the thread the control was original created on. The calling back to itself just makes it callable from any thread. However, to ensure this isn't the issue, I went ahead and gave it a try. The same thing happens where the debugger gets to the `Invoke()` line, seems to step into it, and then ignores/continues and never reaches the statement again although it certainly should.

Comment: The actual call to the invoked method will be on the GUI thread not the current one so it will not get stepped into. Try setting a break point within the area where the GUI gets updated and you should catch the processing of the other thread.

Comment: Still a no go. I've got breakpoints on the lines which should execute next as well as many others which should be hit within my loop. None of them are being hit after I continue/step-into the next statement after `Invoke()`. I should also note that running this without any breakpoints to debug does not update that `textbox` at all, which is where this effort started.

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know why the debugger was "breaking" on that `Invoke` call.

However, I've fixed the threading issue I had which was causing the `Invoke` to be problematic, so I am no longer facing this issue.

I created the `thread` in my `GUI.h` file upon clicking a Start `button`, instead of later on in the program where the thread could be created in the `GUI.cpp` file.

**To try to be more specific**, my `Button_Click` method (in `GUI.h`) calls a method which is declared in `GUI.h` and defined in `GUI.cpp`. I was originally creating the thread in the GUI.cpp function. *Now*, I create the thread in the `Button_Click` method in `GUI.h` and let that thread call the method in `GUI.cpp`. The method in `GUI.cpp` calls a method to `SetTextBoxText`. That method can now `Invoke` itself if a thread other than the owning thread is calling it (which in my case is always).

That's my fix. If anyone can explain why that makes threading safer, I'd love to know.